# Javafx does'nt work properly on Ubuntu 16.04 in java desktop application

Tags: java, javafx, webview, ubuntu-16.04

when i set the size of splash screen in webview,all the design of the inner html get destorted.The background of the buttons does'nt show and scrollbars does'nt appear.overall design is affected by it.Please give me the solution of this problem..How will javafx work properly in ubuntu 16.04 version.

Comment: The inner HTML of the splash screen? Solution would be an image, screenshot of correct HTML.

Comment: Splash is created in javafx webview.when scroll is appeared in the splash due to less size ,then all the designs of the softwares work properly,when we give the proper size to the splash...and we remove the scroll,designs does'nt show properly